# Prevent auto-formatting in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019. In `Options > Text Editor > C#  > Code Style > Formatting` untick all the `Automatically format` options. Great! Now when I type or paste something into the editor it stays there.

How do I prevent automatic formatting in `Visual Basic`? Wasn't able to find the options.

(PS: We have tonnes of legacy VB code. This will be upgraded to C# when an opportunity arises.)

Comment: It's under `Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced > Pretty listing (reformatting) of code` - and some other options too.

Comment: @Dai: That seems to do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting my comment to an answer):

It's under `Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced > Pretty listing (reformatting) of code` - and there's some other options there too that might interest you.

[image]